# What is the format of TSQL STATS_STREAM (undocumented feature)? Does it contain all the Statistics Data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, table-statistics

I have a huge table on one server, and need to copy the table to the production server. I can do this, but then I need to generate statistics, which will take a long time on a system that I don't want to ask to handle a huge job. If I move the entire database, I need to take down the system in order to remove the existing database, which is a no-no.

Pinal Dave has a post, http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/05/sql-server-copy-statistics-from-one-server-to-another-server/
In the post, he outlines how to copy statistics from one table to a new one using Microsoft's "Generate Scripts," which allows copying via the undocumented STATS_STREAM feature. This is for a new table. I'm not sure if I can create a table with the statistics and then write in all of the data, since that should make the system want to update the statistics - possibly even if I have autogenerate statistics off.

I am using the following code: (The Table is InvTbl, and the statistics on that table I am updating is GammaTheta. The statistics exist, and the data is there.)

```
Update STATISTICS dbo.InvTbl [GammaTheta]  WITH STATS_STREAM = 0x0100002000...
```

First, does anyone know if Stats_Stream contains all of the statistics data? Then, importantly, how is it being stored in binary?

Note: The table stores a statistical distribution of two variables which we look up based on a join, and has some really important features about the distribution of the inputs. It is static, and I will never need to recalculate the values or the stats once loaded. Not using fullscan is not an option, based on testing, as join speed matters and is affected.

Note 2: No, the number does not end with an ellipsis. I left the data off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, the stats stream is a binary representation of the statistics data and can be used to fully re-create the statistics, even on another table with different data (though the same schema).  Kevin Kline blogged about that [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kevin_kline/archive/2012/03/16/dev-advice-make-a-tiny-dev-database-act-like-a-huge-prod-database.aspx).  I took a swing at better automation of it [here](http://www.spartansql.com/2012/03/scripting-out-statistics.html).

Comment: Does a clone database retain the same statistics after copying additional data into the database?

Comment: Statistics are updated only when you issue an explicit 'update statistics' statement or if either of 'is_auto_update_stats_on' or 'is_auto_update_stats_async_on' is set for your database and ~10% of your data has changed since the stats were last updated. Any way you slice it though, stats aren't maintained in real time like indexes are.

Comment: I need it not to update even when I add rows. I can keep auto_update off, I guess.